# runtimeservice.getVariables does not work because it can't find process instance id

Tags: flowable

I'm new to flowable and I'm trying to start a process instance with variables. `params` here is the Map of `<String,Object>` that I'm using to start the process. It all goes well, but if I try to get my variables back it tells me

```
"execution 22f42f67-5f88-11e9-9df0-d46d6dbfea92 doesn't exist"
```

But if I search for it in my process instances list, is there. This is what I do:

```
pi = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceById(processDefinitionId, params);
runtimeService.getVariables(pi.getId());
```

I'm stuck with this problem and I do not understand why it keeps doing this. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flowable has the concept of `RuntimeService` and `HistoryService`. The first one contains only the runtime data (what is currently active) and the second one has all the data. The runtime data is a subset of the history data.

The reason why you can’t find the variables via the `RuntimeService` is due to the fact that the process is completed.

If you use the `HistoryService` then it would work as expected.

Comment: If you came here, but your process-instance is unfinished, as in my case, maybe you took the task id for the process instance id ... as I did :-/